# INSERT INTO SQL ERROR

Tags: mysql, sql

I created a simple mysql query to run when an user uploads a file. The query is meant to created a new row in the table dress and attach the name of the file to a column titled file_name. However, phpmyadmin tells me that when I run the query in the SQL section I am unable to do so because it gives me this error.

`#1054 - Unknown column 'name' in 'field list'`

Here is my query code. I suspect it is an syntax error.

```
INSERT INTO `dress` (file_name) VALUES (name)
```

Also, here is my info on my database

```
dress   CREATE TABLE `dress` (
 `primary_id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
 `file_name` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
 `match_1` varchar(100) NOT NULL,
 PRIMARY KEY (`primary_id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=4 DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1
```

Comment: Try `INSERT INTO \`dress\` (file_name) VALUES ('name')`

Comment: Quotes will get you around the error, as others have said. Keep in mind, though, that since match_1 is a NOT NULL field, you'll have to give a value for that, too.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you're trying to insert the value 'name', you should put it in quotes - like this:

```
INSERT INTO `dress` (file_name) VALUES ('name')
```

Answer (score 3):

You have to add single or double qoutes around the value:

```
INSERT INTO `dress` (file_name) VALUES ('name');
```